# How to add a flag to jira issue via rest api

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I would like to be able to add a flag to an issue via the Jira API. I was unable to find any documentation regarding this issue. Does anyone know how this works?

Comment: When you say "add a flag", what is it you are trying to do.  Normally you would add a custom field to the issues through the UI then you can set the  custom field using the API.

Comment: By 'flag' do you mean label?

Comment: Flagging an issue is a jira implemented construct. https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/working-with-issues/flagging-an-issue I would just really like to be able to do this via the api.

Answer (score 6):

I've figured out how to do this, I'm not sure on the version of the API. I made a `POST` request to:

*yourdomain* `/rest/greenhopper/1.0/xboard/issue/flag/flag.json`

And in the body (replace JIRA-ISSUE with your issue key):

`{"issueKeys":["JIRA-ISSUE"],"flag":true}`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the best answer I found.
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/38062844/answers/38062897

There is a field called Flagged. It is a checkbox type field. There is a single value by default, Impediment. The field is checked for null status. If the field is null, the issue is not flagged. If the field is not null, the issue is flagged.

You would use the REST API for this. Examples are here –

```
https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue.
```

You'll either need to know the field ID (customfield_10000) or you need to to script the discovery of the field by searching the metadata –          https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-discovering-meta-data-for-creating-issues.

An example of setting a custom field while creating the issue over API –

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data {"fields":{"project":{"key":  "TEST"}, "summary": "Always do right. This will gratify some people and  astonish the REST.", "description": "Creating an issue while setting custom  field values", "issuetype":{"name": "Bug"}, "customfield_10000": [{"value":  "Impediment"}]}} -H "Content-Type: application/json"    http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/
non-minified data  Expand source
{
"fields": {
   "project":
   { 
      "key": "TEST"
   },
   "summary": "Always do right. This will gratify some people and astonish the REST.",
   "description": "Creating an issue while setting custom field values",
   "issuetype": {
      "name": "Bug"
   },       
   "customfield_10000": [ {"value": "Impediment" }]       
  }
}
```

Comment: But depend update is motive error `Field 'customfield_10000' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.`.. not 100%

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/working-with-issues/flagging-an-issue), "Flagged" is a checkbox custom field that accepts a single value "Impediment".

You should be able to set it using the JIRA REST API just like any other custom field. Maybe the examples [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-edit-issues) will help.

You can also set custom field values using the JIRA Java API.

Comment: Wild guesses are not helpful.  As stated above, when you try to do this you end up with a vague and unhelpful "cannot be set" error.  This may work like any other custom field -- maybe -- but the formatting is uncertain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with this right now. It seems that the Flagged field is not a checkbox type field anymore, but multicheckbox. So the data format I need to send to Jira Cloud API to set the flag in my case look like this:

```
{update:
  {customfield_10021:
    [{set:
      [{id:“10019”}]
    }]
  }
}
```

To remove the flag the data I sent to Jira look like this:

```
{update:
  {customfield_10021:
    [{set:
      []
    }]
  }
}
```

In the above **customfield_10021** is Flagged field's key and **10019** is id that sets the flag. Both of them you need to figure out for your Jira Cloud instance for example by aquiring issue with set Flagged field and checking how it is set.

Just to make it clear, to add/remove a flag I use edit issue end point described [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueidorkey-put).
Also, to be able to add/remove flag the Flagged field has to be on the edit screen of the issue type that you want to modify and your user needs to have proper priviliges.

Answer (score 0):

I spent like 3 hours trying to figure it out and it always gave back "Field 'customfield_10021' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.". To fix it, simply click on Settings Icon -> Issues -> Custom Fields. Search for "Flagged" click on "Screens", Add or remove associated screens" and just add it to all screens. Then it works perfectly.