# Problems flagging/unflagging JIRA issues using jira-python

Tags: python, api, jira

I use the [Python JIRA API wrapper](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/jira) almost daily to log time, add comments, and transition issues. Recently my team decided to replace the "Roadblock" status with an "Impediment" flag. My issue is that I cannot flag/unflag an issue from within an issue (https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSWSERVER-16346).

The following code to update `customfield_10500` (the flag) does not work:

```
jira = JIRA(options=options, basic_auth=(os.getenv('user'), os.getenv('pass')))

i = jira.issue('BIS-9')

i.update(fields={
    'customfield_10500' : {'value' : 'Impediment'}
})
```

The error

```
JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url

response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_10500":"Field 'customfield_10500' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}
```

I know the field must be set within the Kanban board, but I don't know how to do this using the Python wrapper.

**Is there a way to do this?**

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207635/how-to-add-a-flag-to-jira-issue-via-rest-api) but don't know how to translate it.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to update a customfield through RestApi the customfield should be added into the Edit Mode Screen.

I believe this is why it is showing the above error

Comment: This is the Jira flag.  you can't add it to a screen.  It is implicitly there on all tickets.  Please don't guess on answers.